# Cheap Rails hosting solution for a aspiring utility application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, hosting, web-hosting

My google-fu skills doesn't seem to fetch any absolute result. I have developed this neat utility app, not expecting to drive all the traffic, but be useful to the one needing it.

Since its non profit utility I don't/cannot afford to spend more than 5~7 dollars/mo. There is the heroku free solution, and AWS solution. But are those enough to drive my applications request and database space need?.

Data space requirement is not above 300 mb(app+database). I am expecting not more than 20 concurrent users. Heroku offers no more than 5 MB in database, hence its out of question.

Dreamhost has an offering for 8.90 per month but with unlimited storage and bandwith. Seems to me as an overkill for my small application whats your thought, any suggestions is appreciated greatly?

Comment: Shove advertising on it and raise some money. Or find another way to generate an income from it so you can afford a decent host. Or, just get an old Ubuntu box and run it from home.

Comment: note that heroku dev DB is no longer for 5mb, but for 10000 rows.

Comment: Nick, yeah I came to know that, I am very happy about it. Simon, Internet connectivity is very unreliable in India, I want to provide decent up-time so running it from home is not an option and advertizing well that's going to happen if I don't have any options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using heroku + AWS you can use the free tier which gives you free stuff for a year - free storage and traffic to storage using S3, free email using SES, etc..

this will help you figure out if you app is worth it or not, without the extra fuss of managing the system.

If after a year you decide to keep it going, you can upgrade the DB if needed for 9$, and the aws costs (for 300mb) would be very minimal being about 10cents per GB

[AWS free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)

[Heroku Database Plans](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql#basic)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 is working terrifically well for me using Ruby, Rails, MySQL, Postgres, Apache, Ubuntu, and the like.

Amazon is generally lower cost than Heroku, if you're comfortable doing your own systems administration, and not counting the time you spend doing it.